# How can i handle execption at pipeline level in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel

I am using apache camel xml dsl for creating on the routes.
And i want to handle exceptions using the errorHandlerRef. But that can be used with route tag only.
Here is my route context:

```
<routeContext id="myRoute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler" id="myErrorRoute">
        <from uri="activemq:queue:{{my.queue}}" />
        <multicast>
            <pipeline>
       //setting headers and other properties
                <to uri="spring-redis://localhost:6379?serializer=#stringSerializer" />
            </pipeline>
            <pipeline>
      //want to put error handling here
      <log message="Insert to DB" />
      <to uri="mybatis:insertToDB?statementType=InsertList"></to>
            </pipeline>
        </multicast>
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

Is there any way i can handle exception at pipeline level.
For example, here i want to make different error handler for both the pipelines. How can i achive this?
I tried putting errorHanlerRef with pipeline tags, but there was compilation error with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of camel 2.0, it can be done using the doTry, doCatch and doFinally as described here http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html and can be implemented as follows:

```
<doTry>
    <to uri="mybatis:insertToDB?statementType=InsertList"></to>
    <doCatch>
        <exception>java.io.IOException</exception>
        <to uri="mock:catch"/>
        <log message="Exception message : ${exception.message}"
            loggingLevel="ERROR" />
    </doCatch>
    <doFinally>
        <to uri="mock:finally"/>
    </doFinally>
 </doTry>
```